# Yahoo pipe using XPath Fetch Page showing null

Tags: xpath, pipe, fetch, yahoo

I'm building a Yahoo Pipe using the XPath Fetch Page module. You can see my pipe [here](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=2375031d30a623ade2235d032ca5443f).

I can see the right information shown in the Debugger, showing 13 items, but when I run my pipe I'm getting the List with 13 items as null.

Already tried choosing the "Emit items as string" option in Xpath Fetch Page module and then doing a regex to get rid of the unwanted HTML code, but I'm getting the same result on running.

Can you guide me on the right direction on how to fix this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Found the answer for this one myself, I had to add a Rename module to change the item.content to title connect the Rename module to a Regex module to use the item.title and this Regex module to the Output. It is not a clean solution, but it works. You can see the edited pipe in [here](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.edit?_id=2375031d30a623ade2235d032ca5443f)